# Can't get wifi working on Ubuntu Server 16.04 + BCM4322

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, wifi-driver, networkmanager

I've tried using networkmanager to connect to wifi using nmtui, the wifi card gets an IP, but there's no network connection, ping to gateway doesn't work either. Also tried using nmcli with

```
nmcli dev wifi connect <SSID> password <password>
```

but the same thing happened. Tried wpasupplicant + /etc/network/interfaces but that didn't work either. Firmware is installed for the wifi card.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 desktop I use the contributed driver package `broadcom-sta-dkms` for my BroadCom BCM4313, and it works fine, apart from the need to sign it manually every time a kernel update is installed, to avoid disabling Secure Boot. The same driver supports the BCM4322, and it's in the Multiverse repository, or it can be down-loaded direct from [here](https://pkgs.org/download/broadcom-sta-dkms).

Comment: The wifi card works, it gets an IP from the DHCP server, the problem isn't with the driver/firmware